# Objective C NSAutoreleasePool and release

Tags: objective-c, release, nsautoreleasepool

I am newbie in Xcode 4.

Recently I am debugging a Objective C program. I write a function that like this:

```
-(void) func{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Product *product=(Product *)[appDelegate.productData objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(product.Name);
    [product release];
    [pool release];
}
```

The funny thing is that I have add the product release (because I don't realize the pool release code at the early debugging...)

When I run the program, it halt by EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
After I remove the product release, it run correctly.
I really don't know if the product object is release or not at the end.
And I am not sure this is the main point that create the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
So I want to ask this question to ensure everything. Is that create the error?

Answer (score 3):

In Objective C - memory handling concept is very simple - Object Ownership.
If i am going to allocate a object i.e. increase its retain count by 1, then its my responsibility to decrease that count.

Now as here you are not allocating any new memory to product object, you are just referring an existing memory. So you won't need to release that.

you can can more on autorelease pool and release in - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1 and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: Well, I search some document in google and found that "the object release which it can be autoreleased will cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS". And basically the product in the code is just a pointer that is no need to release.  But I found that is very hard to identify which object will be autorelease in the code. In this situation, I will consider how to prevent this situation. Can I use NSAutorelease pool in all function, never call release manually and use autorelease in all returned object to prevent this situation?